# Debugging Android SDK source older than target SDK

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I have an Android app (target API 19), but is a bad bug (force close) in API 16. How can I debug this app (incl. Android sources)? I'm using Android Studio and within the debugger AS only shows API 19 Sources, which is not really useful for my problem.

Comment: Are you asking for API 16 source code? or you want run your app on a API 16 emulator?

Comment: I use Genymotion with API 16. My app is installed and crashed there, but my app runs perfectly on API 19. Is it possible to step through the source code in AS while debugging (but not the app target API).

Comment: I'd never tried that tool, but when you use android standard emulator or any device with adb connection, you can debug your app and go through all the android sdk codes while your app running/debugging... so my suggestion is setup an android emulator with AVD and run your app on it.

Comment: I found the failure. It was a real bug in API 16 -> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35466 - I used the stacktrace and opened the source manual in an editor.